# JQuery div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this jquery code here and for what ever reason its not displaying at all :(.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    done();
});

function done() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        updates();
        done();
    }, 200);
}

function updates() {
    $.getJSON("./fetch.php", function(data) {
        $("ul").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function(){
            $("ul").append("<div class=\"progress progress-success\"><div style=\"width: " +this['health']+"%");
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

The HTML code for the progress bar is

```
<div class="progress progress-success"><div style="width: 100%" class="bar"></div></div>
```

Comment: Apart from it being everything else but a good idea to make a request every 200 milliseconds, a UL can not have DIV as children.

Comment: a `ul` can only have a li as a direct child. A `li` can have pretty much ANYTHING inside of it

Comment: So what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: either take your div outside of your ul change your div to an li

Comment: like so?             $("ul").append("<li class=\"progress progress-success\"><div style=\"width: " +this['health']+"%");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should fix it like:

```
$("ul").empty();
$.each(data.result, function(){
    $("ul").append('<li><div class="progress progress-success"><div style="width: '+this['health']+'%" class="bar"></div></div></li>');
});
```